# Connecting two tables using third table with foreign key in mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    userID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username text NOT NULL,
    password text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (userID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS schedule (
    actID int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    actName text NOT NULL,
    actDay text NOT NULL,
    actStart text NOT NULL,
    actStop text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (actID)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS connection (
    userID int,
    actID int,
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(userID),
    FOREIGN KEY (actID) REFERENCES schedule(actID)
);
```

I am using a third table (`connection`) to connect the first two tables (`users` and `schedule`) with `FOREIGN KEY`. How can I get all activities from `schedule` for a specific user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search by user's name you must join all 3 tables:

```
select u.*, s.*
from users u
inner join connection c on c.userID = u.userID
inner join schedule s on s.actID = c.actID
where u.username = ?
```

If you want to search by user's id you must join only 2 tables:

```
select c.userID, s.*
from connection c inner join schedule s 
on s.actID = c.actID
where c.userID = ?
```

If a user does not have any activities but you want in the results 1 row, with no activity then use left joins:

```
select u.*, s.*
from users u
left join connection c on c.userID = u.userID
left join schedule s on s.actID = c.actID
where u.username = ?
```

Comment: It worked great but what does c, u and s stand for?

Comment: They are aliases of the tables involved in the joins. Every column should be qualified with the table's name to avoid ambiguities.